# Multiple Page Development in Java with Eclipse and GWT

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I have been writing some basic code for an application I am designing.  I have learned the basics and gotten some simple database connection working with **RPC** calls etc.  What I need to do now and am completely lost (as I am traditionally a **c#** developer with windows forms).

In **c#** if I wanted a new form I would just create it, and then call the `show` method.

How does one create multiple pages in **GWT**, and switch between them?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to

1. Make a new java class (GwtHome.java, GwtHelp.java etc)
2. Extend these classes by using the Composite class
3. Make the equivalent of a Master Page and add it to the rootPanel as a class with the appropriate headers, menu, footer and Content Placeholder (Could be any of the AbsolutePanel, VerticalPanel, HorizontalPanel objects provided by the GWT Framework)
4. By clicking on the menu clear the Placeholder and add the appropriate object of GwtHome, GwtHelp etc.

After getting aquanted with the above procedure, you might want to break up the code in many files using a design pattern as suggested by Andrei.

Comment: Thank you Sir.  This is exactly what I needed to know.  GWT Designer allows me to build composites.

Answer (score 1):

Simply clear the root panel (`RootPanel.get().clear()`) and add the widget for your new "page", the same way you added your first one.

If you're using LayoutPanels, do `RootLayoutPanel.get().clear()` instead.

Comment: so, to create the widgets I see EntryPoint,Composite,DialogBox, PopupView, MVPView...which one of these would I use for a full page?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "full page". In a GWT application, there is only one page, ever. Look at the code in your onModuleLoad: it creates some widget and adds it to the root panel. When you want to switch "pages", in whatever code you're running in response to whatever event, you clear the root panel, construct your new "page" widget and stick it in there. The code to do that will look just like your code in onModuleLoad. When you want to get back to yuor first page, in whatever code you're running then, you'll want the same code that's in your onModuleLoad.

Comment: Thank you.  I am aware of the one page situation.  What I meant to say was how to mimic multiple pages.  I am looking to see how to build each page.  Thanos answered my question below.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Activities and Places design pattern: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

I highly recommend it for a multipage GWT app. It explains pretty well how you create different "views", that are driven by their "activities", and tied to specific "places" (pages) that users can navigate.

Typically you use a LayoutPanel as your "page" container that occupies the entire available browser window. You split this LayoutPanel into 2-3 layers (zones), like top menu, side menu, main area. Each area contains one widget, usually a ScrollPanel, FlowPanel,  or HtmlPanel. Then you use different widgets or HTML inside each of these widgets to display whatever you need. You may also create your own composite widgets that you can reuse in different pages.

Comment: I looked at this design.  I will do more study into it, but at the moment seems a bit complicated.  Thank you for your help.